# How to ignore all private member using compodoc?

Tags: angular, storybook, compodoc

I've set up **compodoc** and it's successfully generating a `documentation.json` file, however, it's documenting all private members of my components and cluttering the UI (in my case it's the storybook UI).

Of course, I can add the `@ignore` **jsdoc** string, but I'd prefer not to clutter my components' **jsdocs** if I can avoid it.

Is it possible to configure **compodoc** to ignore all private members?

Comment: Does [`--disablePrivate`](https://compodoc.app/guides/options.html#:~:text=documentation%20coverage%20report-,%2D%2DdisablePrivate,-Do%20not%20show) do what you are looking for?

Comment: That did work. See link to configure in angular: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/14147